# Lasso 9 Compatibility with Lasso 8 define_tag Syntax

Tags: lasso-lang

I have a fairly complex Lasso 8 method (custom tag) that I want to run in both Lasso 8 and Lasso 9. (During our transition to Lasso 9 we have setup virtual hosts pointing to the same web root with different host names.) I have simplified the Lasso 8 method down to the following, and it will still not run in Lasso 9:

```
<?LassoScript

define_tag('old8method', -required='input', -type='string');
    return(#input);
/define_tag;

old8method('test');

?>
```

Results in the following error from Lasso 9:

> Error Code: -1 Error Msg: Position was out of range: 0 max is 1 Error
>   Stack:
>
> 3:1 myfile.lasso

Whether working with my 200-line method or this simplified test, the error is the same.

Any suggestions for modifying the Lasso 8 define_tag code so that Lasso 9 works with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the initial release of 9.2.6. If on Linux, try updating using your package manager. If OS X, download the latest installer from the LassoSoft website and re-install. If that doesn't fix it, revert back to 9.2.5 and file a bug with LassoSoft for the specific platform you're using.

Comment: This is indeed a bug in 9.2.6 which will be fixed for 9.2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the example provided and it worked fine for me (9.2.5 OSX)

It may be worth restarting your instance incase there are lingering signatures causing confusion. It's possible that an old definition is being triggered causing the error you see.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you wrap your definitions in a conditional. Thus being able to provide both 8.X and 9.X definitions in the same file.

```
if(lasso_version >> '9.');
    define old8method(input::string);
        return #input;
    /define;
else;
    define_tag('old8method', -required='input', -type='string');
        return(#input);
    /define_tag;
/if;
```

Answer (score 0):

Jono from [LassoSoft](http://www.lassosoft.com) on the [LassoTalk list](http://www.lassosoft.com/LassoTalk/) points out that this is a known bug in 9.2.6, which I am using.

I will await 9.2.7 before resuming development. Thanks to all for your responses.

-Justin